# How to get last table entry from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, max

I have a form in file1.php where I enter News article, which is send to MYSQL. What I want to do is to display entered data on file2.php from MYSQL using MAX(id).

Here is my PHP code:

File1.php

```
if (isset($_POST['Publish'])) 

$Name = $_POST["Name"];
$Content = $_POST["Content"];
$NewsType = $_POST["NewsType"];
$Author = $_POST["Author"];
$Date = $_POST["Date"];

mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mysql_selectdb('dbname') or die (mysql_error());
$query = "INSERT INTO `table`
            (`Name`, `Content`, `NewsType`, `Author`, `Date`)
            VALUES
            ('$Name','$Content','$NewsType','$Author','$Date')";
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
header ('Location: File2.php');
mysql_close();
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Not the error but please look into using PDO or MySQLi

Comment: i think you are asking for last inserted id ?

Comment: @asprin auto_increment columns offer no guarantee that the last insert has the largest value

Comment: Also, your SQL is subjected to SQL Injection as you directly put `$_POST` values into the query without any filtering

Comment: @Noino Is it? I reckon it defeats the purpose of auto increment then if the last insert isn't the maximum value

Comment: @asprin auto_increment simply guarantees a unique value, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Noino You were right. But in the OP's case, there is no manual insertion of `id` value and hence it will always be in ascending order on every insert.

Comment: @asprin manual insertion of id has nothing to do with it. The id may be the ascending, and usually is, but it is by no means always so. For example: http://codership.blogspot.fi/2009/02/managing-auto-increments-with-multi.html

Answer (score 1):

On a page like this, you can use `mysql_insert_id()` and redirect to `File2.php?id=$lastid` to display the inserted article

```
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$lastid = mysql_insert_id();
header ('Location: File2.php?id='.$lastid);
```